# Spring Cloud Data Flow http-source application with Oauth2 Security Config

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

I was trying to configure the Oauth2 server on http-source-kafka connector in SCDF. There are no such properties available to configure the Oauth2 related configs.

```
permitted.endpoints=xxx
restricted.endpoints=xxxxx
scopes=xxxx
resourceId=xxxx
```

Want to know how I can enable security for "http-source-kafka connector" in SCDF. So that I can restrict the rest endpoints as per my needs.

Answer (score 0):

The HTTP source app does not have OAuth security enabled. You would need to extend the app to add the `spring-security-oauth2-client` to the classpath and then follow [these steps](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#web.security.oauth2) to configure the access. This [guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#extend-classpath) shows how to extend the classpath.